# How to make cell color change on double click tornadofx

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I need to make cells color in my `tableview` be changed by right mouse click. My code:

```
cellFormat { _ ->
    graphicProperty().addListener { _ ->
        setOnMouseClicked {
            if (it.button == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
                style {
                    backgroundColor += c("darkred")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

second variant:

```
cellFormat { _ ->
                style {
                setOnMouseClicked { button ->
                    if (button.button == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                        backgroundColor += c("darkred")
                    }
                }
            } }
```

I understand that I need to make cell format listener, however I tried different ways and have no result. Can anyone give me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are marking selections for a later operation.  Have you considered a multi-select list with a CSS style applied to selected items?

A checkbox could also be used to mark off records if you have need for a parallel selection mechanism.